# Count field from 2nd table

Tags: count, having

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
select
t1.Field1
t1.Field2
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.Field1 = t1.Field1
where
t1.Field3 like '123-%'
and t1.CreateDate >= '01/01/2021'
having
Count(t2.Field4 = 419) >= 1
```

2 tables
Table 1 has unique records with an ID (Field 1)
Table 2 has multiple records, with ID Field 1 as well.  Table2 may have 10, 20, etc records for Field1.  I'm wanting to pull Table1 records where Table2 as at least 1 occurrence of Field4 = 419.  Table2 may not have any Field4=419, it may have 1, or it may have 2 or more.

Pretty straight forward I think, but unfortunately I'm new to SQL writing which I why I'm posting for help as I've tried several ways to get this to work without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you use `having` when you have a `group by` in your query.

There will be multiple ways of writing what you want, but one way that I think is easy to understand is selecting from Table1 and doing the count of Table2 in a subquery of the `where` clause. Depending on the size of your tables and the indexing, you might want to explore other options, but I think this is at least a good starting point that does what you want.

```
select
 t1.Field1
 t1.Field2
from Table1 t1
where
 t1.Field3 like '123-%'
 and t1.CreateDate >= '01/01/2021'
 and (SELECT count(*) FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.Field1 = t1.Field1 AND t2.Field4 = 419) >= 1
```